# How to change ListBox selection background color?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, background, selection

It seems to use default color from Windows settings which is blue by default.
Let's say I want to change it to red permanently. I'm using Winforms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You must override the [`Drawitem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx) event and set the [`DrawMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode.aspx) property to [`DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode.aspx)

Check this sample:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0) return;

    // If the item is selected them change the back color.
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics, 
                                  e.Font, 
                                  e.Bounds, 
                                  e.Index,
                                  e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                  e.ForeColor, 
                                  Color.Yellow); // Choose the color.

    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    e.DrawBackground();

    // Draw the current item text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

    // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I managed to apply this code but the items on the listbox have white color on the background and foreground. I can't see why it would do that?

Comment: do you set the property `DrawMode` to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise if at Normal it is the default windows color.

Comment: Do you assign the event handler DrawItem  like this `this.listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox1_DrawItem);`?

Comment: Oops I forgot to override. Sorry for your trouble! It works as intended now. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than using `listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString()` to get the string to draw, consider using `listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items[e.Index])`. The latter will take into account the `DisplayMember` property if you are using data binding.

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully this will help someone in the future as the above code helped me but not 100%

I still had the following problems:
- when i selected another index, the newly selected index would also highlight red.
- when i changed the font size of the listbox, the highlighted area would be to small.

Below fixes that problem

- change the DrawMode to ownerdrawvariable
- create a MeasurItem and DrawItem event for the listbox

```
private void lstCartOutput_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
   // Cast the sender object back to ListBox type.
   ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
   e.ItemHeight = listBox.Font.Height;
}

private void lstCartOutput_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
   e.DrawBackground();
   Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;

   if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
   {
      myBrush = Brushes.Red;
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 64)), e.Bounds);
   }

   else
   {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);

   }

   e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds);
   e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

I also referenced the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem.aspx) website.

Answer (score 2):

The below code does exactly what you are saying:

In the InitializeComponent method:

```
this.listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem);
this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

And the event handlers:

```
void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.listBox1.Invalidate();
}

void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.Index;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    foreach (int selectedIndex in this.listBox1.SelectedIndices)
    {
        if (index == selectedIndex)
        {
            // Draw the new background colour
            e.DrawBackground();
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
        }
    }

    // Get the item details
    Font font = listBox1.Font;
    Color colour = listBox1.ForeColor;
    string text = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();

    // Print the text
    g.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (float)e.Bounds.X, (float)e.Bounds.Y);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Code is taken from:

http://www.weask.us/entry/change-listbox-rsquo-selected-item-backcolor-net

Comment: I'm getting a problem with this. The selection changes to red but it also stays on all items that I previously selected, defeating the purpose of having a "visual" one selected item. What could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Why use ListBox in the first place and not replace it with a single-column, no-headers-visible, read-only DataGridView, which is fully customisable?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

Unfortunately my datasource is a List of Entity Class. So I have the same code with the accepted answer above but with minor modification to select the exact property on my Class that I need on DrawString for my ListBox:

```
 if (e.Index < 0) return;
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                      e.Font,
                                      e.Bounds,
                                      e.Index,
                                      e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                      e.ForeColor,
                                      Color.Yellow);

  e.DrawBackground();
  //This is my modification below:
  e.Graphics.DrawString(ctListViewProcess.Items.Cast<entMyEntity>().Select(c => c.strPropertyName).ElementAt(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
  e.DrawFocusRectangle();
```