# Colour Individual Items in a winforms ComboBox?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a dilemma whereby I have a form which contains a number of comboboxes that contain information/options/items that may be invalid/out-of-date in certain circumstances.

I can't simply remove the out-of-date information from the items, but I do want to give the user a visual-clue when options are invalid.

I was thinking of colouring in the Items (probably red) to indicate if & when they are invalid.  I don't necessarily need to prevent a user from selecting an invalid option, just make them visually aware that they are doing so.

Can this be done? Can you - dyamically - change the colo(u)r of combobox items?

Thanks,

Comment: Damn, I'm not gonna override default item draw behavior. Must take something else besides ComboBox.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You may try DrawItem event of ComboBox. Keep your dates on a list and compare them with ID's and brush your items.

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{    
    // Draw the background 
    e.DrawBackground();        

    // Get the item text    
    string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();

    // Determine the forecolor based on whether or not the item is selected    
    Brush brush;
    if (YourListOfDates[e.Index] < DateTime.Now)// compare  date with your list.  
    {
        brush = Brushes.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        brush = Brushes.Green;
    }

    // Draw the text    
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

To fire this event (thanks to @Bolu)

> You need to change ComboBox.DrawMode
>   to OwnerDrawFixed/OwnerDrawVariable to
>   fire the comboBox_DrawItem

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  the `// Determine the forecolor based on whether or not the item is selected` is throwing me off a little though, there appears to be no code below to support selection or not...  I don't think I really need this functionality, Just wondering if this is a c&p error or something I need to be aware of?

Comment: So you'll be doing this operation on selectedIndexChanged? If so you can't use this. This determines the colors on load and checks if the dates you have are earlier than today or not. If you only need this for selected Item, I don't think there is a way of doing it other then reloading your items and painting only the item you want to red with this event.

Comment: I need it for all items.  On top of this It's my intention to cascade the effect to other comboboxes on my form, based on my own "valid/not-valid" rules.   So you select an item from CBO#1 and the result is `some` items from CBO#2 & CBO#3 are now invalid to choose from, and hence need repainted with the new color.

Comment: @Mike, you can modify your criteria of valid/invalid for other combobox items using `SelectedIndexChanged`, then you could dynamically reload `comboBox_DrawItem` with `comboBox.Refresh()`.

Comment: Does comboBox_DrawItem fire when the item is initialized? Hooking on to this event doesn't seem to fire (even once).  Or do I need to do a .refresh to manually cause this?

Comment: From MSDN: Occurs when a visual aspect of an owner-drawn ComboBox changes.

Comment: @Mike, you need to change `ComboBox.DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed`/`OwnerDrawVariable` to fire the `comboBox_DrawItem` event

Comment: @Bolu Thanks. @all can someone edit the answer to include this and I will accept. :)

Comment: string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(); 
Always gives me System.Data.DataRowView and not the actual content

Comment: To color the background of the items you need to re-instantiate a new DrawItemEventArgs element. See example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663704/how-to-change-listbox-selection-background-color

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the ComboBox.DrawMode leads to the element not being displayed in white anymore when having the focus (the blue selection background). Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

```
///The ComboBoxCustom Control:

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
namespace TyroDeveloper
{
    public class ComboBoxCustom:ComboBox
    {
        public ComboBoxCustom() { 
            this.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed; 
        }
        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDrawItem(e);
            e.DrawBackground();
            ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)this.Items[e.Index];
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(item.ForeColor);
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) 
            { brush = Brushes.Yellow; }
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, this.Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
        }
    }
    public class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public ComboBoxItem() { }

        public ComboBoxItem(string pText, object pValue)
        {
            text = pText; val = pValue;
        }

        public ComboBoxItem(string pText, object pValue, Color pColor)
        {
            text = pText; val = pValue; foreColor = pColor;
        }

        string text = "";
        public string Text { 
            get { return text; } set { text = value; } 
        }

        object val;
        public object Value { 
            get { return val; } set { val = value; } 
        }

        Color foreColor = Color.Black;
        public Color ForeColor { 
            get { return foreColor; } set { foreColor = value; } 
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
}

//To add the items:

comboBoxCustom1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("México","0",Color.Green));
comboBoxCustom1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("USA", "1", Color.Blue));
comboBoxCustom1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("China", "2", Color.Red));
```

the source url page:
http://www.tyrodeveloper.com/2012/04/color-in-combobox-item.html

Comment: Saw this answer on your website, then also saw it here.  I'm pleased that I am able to thank you for this excellent solution.

Answer (score 3):

[Changing color of combobox back color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCwRr.jpg)

You can use this codes for changing back color of combobox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Comboboxrenklendir
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void cmbrenkli_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {




        Color HighlightColor = Color.Red;

        if (e.Index >=0)
        {

            //int sayi = cmbrenkli.Items.Count;

            string deger = cmbrenkli.Items[e.Index].ToString();

            if (deger == "30"|| deger == "50")
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(HighlightColor), e.Bounds);
            }



            e.Graphics.DrawString(cmbrenkli.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(cmbrenkli.ForeColor), new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbrenkli.Items.Add("10");
        cmbrenkli.Items.Add("20");
        cmbrenkli.Items.Add("30");
        cmbrenkli.Items.Add("40");
        cmbrenkli.Items.Add("50");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It does not keep the color after selected?

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Color color;
        //Text of your ComboBox element
        string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
        //Check for something
        if (text == "I am red")
        {
            color = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            color = Color.White;
        }
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, new SolidBrush(((ComboBox)sender).ForeColor), new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Use this as DrawItem Event and set DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed or OwnerDrawVariable