# C# combobox color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Colour Individual Items in a winforms ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667532/colour-individual-items-in-a-winforms-combobox)

is any simple example to set custom background color of each item?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms/3709452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your objective by calling  DrawItem of the ComboBox, For reference see the following method.

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Override this function to draw items in the Color comboBox

        // Get the Graphics Object (aka. CDC or Device Context Object )
        // passed via the DrawItemEventArgs parameter
        Graphics g = e.Graphics ;

        // Get the bounding rectangle of the item currently being painted
        Rectangle r = e.Bounds ;

        if ( e.Index >= 0 ) 
        {
            Rectangle rd = r; 
            r.X = r.Right ; 

            // Get the brush object, at the specifid index in the colorArray
            SolidBrush b = (SolidBrush)colorArray[e.Index];
            // Fill a portion of the rectangle with the selected brush
            g.FillRectangle(b, rd);


            // Draw the rectangle
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 2 ), r );

            if ( e.State == ( DrawItemState.NoAccelerator | DrawItemState.NoFocusRect))
            {
                // if the item is not selected draw it with a different color
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White) , r);
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            }
            else
            {
                // if the item is selected draw it with a different color
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue) , r);
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i try to use DrawItem but it not raises

Comment: @kusanagi: Set `ComboBox.DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed or OwnerDrawVariable`

Comment: @kusanagi:in DrawItem again you have to draw your string for each item of the comboBox, By the way have you tried with the above method which I sent you ? Sorry I forgot to say it,
Please set comboBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed