# How to change the ForeColor of individual items in a ComboBox? (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I know I can change the ForeColor of the ComboBox like this:

`comboBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;`

But that makes all the items that color. When you drop down the ComboBox every single item is then red.

I want to individually color items so that the first item is *always* black, the second *always* red, the third *always* blue, et cetera. Is this possible?

Also, I don't think I can create a UserControl for this because the ComboBox I am using is the one for Toolstrips.

Comment: Check this question accepted answer : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667532/colour-individual-items-in-a-winforms-combobox`

Comment: ToolStripComboBox is the difficult requirement, it doesn't support owner draw.  You'll need to use ToolStripControlHost and embed an owner draw regular ComboBox into it.

Comment: Ugh.. This is all sounding like more trouble than it's worth. I think I'll try to think of another way to convey the currently selected item's color to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DrawItem event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

> This event is used by an owner-drawn ComboBox. You can use this event
>   to perform the tasks needed to draw items in the ComboBox. If you have
>   a variable sized item (when the DrawMode property set to
>   DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable), before drawing an item, the MeasureItem
>   event is raised. You can create an event handler for the MeasureItem
>   event to specify the size for the item that you are going to draw in
>   your event handler for the DrawItem event.

MSDN Example:

```
// You must handle the DrawItem event for owner-drawn combo boxes.  
// This event handler changes the color, size and font of an 
// item based on its position in the array.
protected void ComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, 
            System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    float size = 0;
    System.Drawing.Font myFont;
    FontFamily family = null;

    System.Drawing.Color animalColor = new System.Drawing.Color();
    switch(e.Index)
    {
        case 0:
            size = 30;
            animalColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            family = FontFamily.GenericSansSerif;
            break;
        case 1:
            size = 10;
            animalColor = System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen;
            family = FontFamily.GenericMonospace;
            break;
        case 2:
            size = 15;
            animalColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tan;
            family = FontFamily.GenericSansSerif;
            break;
    }

    // Draw the background of the item.
    e.DrawBackground();

    // Create a square filled with the animals color. Vary the size
    // of the rectangle based on the length of the animals name.
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(2, e.Bounds.Top+2, 
            e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height-4);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(animalColor), rectangle);

    // Draw each string in the array, using a different size, color,
    // and font for each item.
    myFont = new Font(family, size, FontStyle.Bold);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(animals[e.Index], myFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X+rectangle.Width, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height));

    // Draw the focus rectangle if the mouse hovers over an item.
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

EDIT :
Just found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667532/colour-individual-items-in-a-winforms-combobox).

Answer (score 1):

For a ToolStripComboBox derive from ToolStripControlHost.

```
//Declare a class that inherits from ToolStripControlHost.
public class ToolStripCustomCombo : ToolStripControlHost
{
    // Call the base constructor passing in a MonthCalendar instance.
    public ToolStripCustomCombo() : base(new ComboBox()) { }

    public ComboBox ComboBox
    {
        get
        {
            return Control as ComboBox;
        }
    }
}
```

Then say you have a toolstrip named m_tsMain. Here's how to add the new control.

```
ToolStripCustomCombo customCombo = new ToolStripCustomCombo();
ComboBox c = customCombo.ComboBox;
c.Items.Add("Hello World!!!");
c.Items.Add("Goodbye cruel world!!!");
m_tsMain.Items.Add(customCombo);
```

And you should be able to add an event handler to c for DrawItem.