# First Item in ComboBox in other color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, combobox

I want my first Item in my ComboBox to have a red font. I also want the ComboBox to look like this, and not like this. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Is it ASP.NET, WinForms or something else?

Comment: have you looked at `DrawItem` event..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341455/how-to-change-the-forecolor-of-individual-items-in-a-combobox-c-winforms

Comment: I tried out the first answer, but I get an error when pasting it in my DrawItem event. The next to last line: "The name 'animals' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: But if I comment that line, the ComboBox have that look that I dont want.

Comment: People say you need to change DrawMode away from Normal, and that makes in look that way... =(

Comment: Are you using windows xp ? Because the look between window's version is different.

Comment: those 2 combobox are in differrent dropdownstyle ..

Comment: Solution: use WPF and forget winforms. It doesn't support customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change combobox's appearance you can set **DropDownStyle** property as **DropDownList** (*it causes to change combobox's behavior; text field is locked and you can't write in it*)

And here is how to change first item's color;

Firstly set combobox's **DrawMode** property as **OwnerDrawFixed** (*unfortunately, this changes causes combobox's appearance turn back old look*) and use **DrawItem** event;

```
private void cmb_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index > -1)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();

        Brush brush = Brushes.Black;

        if (e.Index == 0)
        {
            brush = Brushes.Red;
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString(((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(), ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works, but it's so sad that it changes the appearance as you said. There isn't a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

// Property named "DropDwonStyle" set it to DropDownList  for Like this