# C# How to change the color of Combobox items?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, combobox

Combobox on winform,
combobox fill datatable three column (id,name,status)

```
combobox.displaymember = "name";
combobox.valuemember = "id";
```

I want to change the color of Combobox items for **status column**

Please advice.

Comment: Did anyone heared about this thing in winforms(Status column)? I know this term only in WPF!?

Comment: Status column name in datatable

Comment: see here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667532/colour-individual-items-in-a-winforms-combobox you would have to have the statuses available in a static location or retrieve them from somewhere in the callback if you want to make decisions on the color

Comment: Very vague, but perhaps my answer is along the right lines?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it this far, but there is one bug.
First a few steps.

1. Add a combo box to your form (comboBox1)
2. Change the `DrawItem` event for comboBox1 to `comboBox1_DrawItem` (our method below)
3. EDIT: Change the `Draw Mode` property for comboBox1 to either `OwnerDrawFixed` or `OwnerDrawVariable`
4. Implement `comboBox1_DrawItem`.  Notice that I switch the brush on the `ComboBoxValue.Status`

   ```
   private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
   {  
       Brush brush;
       var g = e.Graphics;
       var rect = e.Bounds;
       var n = "";
       var f = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);

       switch (((ComboBoxValue)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem).Status)
       {
           case "one":
               brush = Brushes.Red;
               break;
           case "two":
               brush = Brushes.Green;
               break;
           default:
               brush = Brushes.White;
               break;
       }
       if (e.Index >= 0)
       {
           n = ((ComboBoxValue)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem).Name;
       }
       g.FillRectangle(brush, rect.X, rect.Y,rect.Width, rect.Height);
       g.DrawString(n, f, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Y);
   }
   ```
5. I used an IList of my own class as the datasource.  Yours will be different.

   ```
   public class ComboBoxValues : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ComboBoxValue>
   {
       public ComboBoxValues()
       {
           this.Add(new ComboBoxValue
           {
               Name = "chad",
               Id = 123,
               Status = "one"
           });
           this.Add(new ComboBoxValue
           {
               Name = "different chad",
               Id = 123,
               Status = "two"
           });
       }
   }
   public class ComboBoxValue
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
   }
   ```
6. Set your `DataSource`

   ```
   comboBox1.DataSource = new ComboBoxValues();
   comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
   comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
   ```

The bug, as you will soon see is that for some reason the colors only seem to change after you mouse over them.  Perhaps someone else will realize the error before i get back to this.  Good luck!

Comment: Have you figured out the mouse over bug?

Comment: @Prix, as this was almost 3 years ago, I dont recall why I didnt post the fix to the bug.  Looking back however, i'm sure it was just a refresh issue.  Try calling refresh on the control after the switch.

Comment: Thanks for the input I solved it by using a custom made combobox, made a question about it as well, as it stuck me else where but also found the answer and posted it ;). For some reason overriding the OnDraw doesn't produce the same issue as you had in here.