# C# ComboBox Item Highlight not working with DrawItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Using the example from the marked answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667532/colour-individual-items-in-a-winforms-combobox) post i came up with this.

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    using (DBDataContext data = new DBDataContext())
    {
        var query = (from a in data.Programs
                     where a.IsCurrentApplication == 1
                     select a.Name).Distinct();
        e.DrawBackground();

        string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();

        Brush brush;
        if (query.Contains(text))
        {
            brush = Brushes.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            brush = Brushes.Black;
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString(text,
            ((Control)sender).Font,
            brush,
            e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
    }            
}
```

What I'm doing is querying a database for applications with a flag. If the flag is true (1), then I change the text of the combobox item to Green. My issue here is that once all the items are drawn. When I hover my cursor of an item, it doesn't highlight. It does however change the darkness of the text slightly. Is there a way i can get the highlighting to work?

Comment: Why not just highlight the control the text is in?  This would make a more profound visual impact and be more noticeable.

Comment: I can try that. I'm not familar how this is done. Do you have any suggestions?  I appreciate your quick response @Brian

Comment: @HiTech querying something in the `DrawItem` event handler is not recommended. the querying may delay the drawing and result in unexpected result.

Comment: @HiTech - It's pretty simple:  `this.comboBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;`.  If this solves your problem, I will convert it to an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @Brian he wants to hightlight the Text of the item in the dropped down list, not the BackColor of the comboBox.

Comment: @KingKing - I understand the question.  I was just suggesting a better, more noticeable way to go about it.

Comment: @KingKing That makes sense, thanks for the tip. How would you improve my example?

Comment: @HiTech your query can be put outside the method, you can init it somewhere else such as in form constructor. However I'm still not sure if it's the issue.

Comment: @Brian Thanks Brian for the suggestion. Unfortunately thats not what I'm looking for. I just need the item in the combo box highlighted.

Comment: @KingKing Okay. I trust you know a thing or two about this so i will give that a shot. Any suggestions on how to solve my Topic issue?

Comment: @HiTech No more suggestion. BTW, have you set the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed`? Although you described about a little change of the Text but it's worth confirming that important condition.

Comment: @KingKing Good looking out. Yes, i have the DrawMode set to OwnerFixedDraw. Without that property set, i don't think the comboBox1_DrawItem event would fire.

Comment: @HiTech your code looks OK to me, even it's almost the same to the code from the link. I've also just tried a simple code like that and it works OK. Have you tried putting the query outside the method `comboBox1_DrawItem`?

Comment: @KingKing You're awesome! That fixed it! Go ahead and make an answer so i can mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, when drawing we should avoid as much *non-drawing* code as possible. In some cases doing so can cause some flicker and in some cases the result is unpredicted. So we should always place such a code outside the drawing route. The `query` in your code should be placed outside your `DrawItem` event handler something like this:

```
public Form1(){
  InitializeComponent();
  using (DBDataContext data = new DBDataContext()) {
    query = (from a in data.Programs
             where a.IsCurrentApplication == 1
             select a.Name).Distinct().ToList();//execute the query right 
  }
}
IEnumerable<string> query;
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
    var combo = sender as ComboBox;
    e.DrawBackground();
    string text = combo.Items[e.Index].ToString();
    Brush brush = query.Contains(text) ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Black;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
}
```