# Change color of Combobox item when item is already in a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012

I have a list of combobox items generated from a database

```
        private void Outlet1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader dr7;
        SqlConnection Conadd1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-PC\\MIKO;Initial Catalog=Caproj;Integrated Security=True;");
        Conadd1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("select Address from [Outlet Table] where ClientID='" + clientid + "'", Conadd1);
        cmd6.Connection = Conadd1;
        dr7 = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt8 = new DataTable();
        dt8.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
        dt8.Load(dr7);
        Outlet1.DisplayMember = "Address";
        Outlet1.DataSource = dt8;

        Conadd1.Close();
        colorcombo();
    }
```

A user can select a certain item in the said combobox and it will be inserted in a listbox. Once the listbox contains the said address, I want the item color to be made red, so it will remind the user that it's already selected

my attempt to code, I have no idea on how to use the drawmode event:

```
  private void colorcombo()
    {
        if (outletlist.Items.Contains(Outlet1.Items.ToString()))
        {
            Con.Open();
            for (int i = Outlet.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Outlet Table] SET [Address] = Address WHERE [Address] = @address", Con))
               {
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", (Outlet.Items[i].Text));
                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    {
                        //Outlet.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Outlet.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Some details:

Outlet1 = name of my combobox

outletlist = name of my listbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colour Individual Items in a winforms ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667532/colour-individual-items-in-a-winforms-combobox)

Comment: I tried using that kind of code, but I get an error whenever I change the condition into the one that I made.

Comment: What kind of error? Which condition?

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'. for the string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(); part of the link you gave

Comment: I just coded it myself and it worked fine. Did you initalized the `EventHandler` correctly?  First you need to change your `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed/OwnerDrawVariable` and then add the `EventHandler` like this ` this.comboBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(comboBox1_DrawItem);`