# How to change the highlight color of a ListBox

Tags: c#, colors, listbox, devexpress, highlight

I am using the ListBox (from DevExpress). The highlight color is a pale orange (?) as shown the picture. How do I change that to blue or something else ?

[image]

Comment: [Click me!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663704/how-to-change-listbox-selection-background-color)

Comment: @brian nice hack (as everything else in winforms), but I don't think the DevExpress version actually requires that.

Comment: [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E789) is a DevExpress response to that.

Comment: @HighCore - BAH!  You _just barely_ beat me to it.

Comment: @brian that doesn't change the fact that winforms is a dinosaur and the only way to get something good out of it is by paying for the DevExpress controls, which are pretty decent (maybe too much for winforms).

Comment: @HighCore I am not sure if this is what I want :/ I want to change the color of the highlight (the strip that highlights the item). I think this is for changing the color of the item itself

Comment: @cemre Im not familiar with the DevExpress winforms controls, but guessing I could tell there must be some property for that in the `e.Appearance`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the theme of the listbox first.

The Theme overrides the changes you make to the `Appereance` property.

[image]

Choose anything but the "Skin" value - if you need to override the colors.

then set the colors you want:

[image]

[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1-SsHUtbJs) video shows how it is done to the XtraGrid - but the prnciple can still be applyed to the listbox.

**EDIT**
if you need change the highligt color - remove the skin (as shown)
and use the DrawItem event:

```
private void listBoxControl1_DrawItem(object sender, ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.State != (DrawItemState.Focus & DrawItemState.Selected))
  {
    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Blue;
  }
}
```

AND you need to set the listBox property

`this.listBoxControl1.HotTrackSelectMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.HotTrackSelectMode.SelectItemOnClick;`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried using the DrawItem event as you suggested but the `e.State == DrawItemState.HotLight` check fails so it didn't work since the body of the if statement is never executed. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: @Cemre hmm the `State` maybe be in more that just that one enum. Try adding `Trace.WriteLine(e.State)` at the top of the event. then test it, and keep an eye on the Output Window

Comment: @Cemre actually I found a more elegant way of duing this. See the opdated answer: notes this: `e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.HotLight)`

Comment: Trace shows that the state is `Selected` and `Focus`. I used `Selected` and also chose style to be flat. It now executes the body of the if statements but color, still, does not change for some reason

Comment: Thanks! I got it solved. I realized I also had the `HighlightedItemStyle = Skinned`  which was preventing it to change color.

Answer (score 3):

Refer: [DevExpress Support Thread - Change FocusedColor in ListBox](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q260549.aspx)

To achieve the desired result, handle the [DrawItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_DrawItemtopic) event and in this event handler, set the `e.Appearance` to get the desired result.

```
private void listBoxControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e) {
    if(e.State == DrawItemState.Focus || e.State== DrawItemState.Selected) {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

For more help go through [DevExpress Search results](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=change%20listbox%20Appearance&p=T4%7CP1%7C4) regarding this.