# How can i remove the blue color wraping the selected item in listBox1 when clicking on item?

Tags: c#, winforms

When i click on a listBox1 to select an item the item stay with blue color around it. How can i remove this color ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the selected item? Or are you trying to deselect it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code to change selection color to the any color you want:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Add this to your form initialization
        this.listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox1_DrawItem);
    }

    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index < 0) return;
        //if the item state is selected them change the back color 
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                      e.Font,
                                      e.Bounds,
                                      e.Index,
                                      e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                      e.ForeColor,
                                      Color.Transparent);//Choose the color

        // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
        e.DrawBackground();
        // Draw the current item text
        e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

I've used transparent as color to remove the background color of selection, but if you want any other color simply change it yourself.
I used this answer as help: [How to change ListBox selection background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663704/how-to-change-listbox-selection-background-color)

**Display on form:**

[image: ListBox Form]

If you want to deselect item on listbox, use either

```
listBox1.ClearSelected();
```

or

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

*Cheers!*

Answer (score 1):

for ListBox  you could write code like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = string.Empty;

    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1) 
        s = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    /// continue you code here .... 
    /// 

    /// after that remove the hilight 

    listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```