# Increase the line spacing in the listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

How do I increase the line spacing in the listbox1?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AIg1.png); [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqvYz.png)
 [image: listbox1]

As well as indenting each string horizontally. And the color of the selected item in the listbox1 red. 
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

["Form1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmSok.png)

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts == null)
            Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts = new List<Account>();

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts != null)
        {
            foreach (var account in Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(account);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2(listBox1).Show();
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem is Account selectedAccount)
        {
            textBox1.Text = selectedAccount.Name;
            textBox2.Text = selectedAccount.Login;
            textBox3.Text = selectedAccount.Password;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts != null)
            Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ItemFormatStyle.Margin = new Padding(5, 10, 2, 2);
    }
}
```

["Form2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrty8.png)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly ListBox _listBox;

    public Form2(ListBox listBox)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _listBox = listBox;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Account account = new Account
        {
            Name = textBox1.Text,
            Login = textBox2.Text,
            Password = textBox3.Text
        };

        _listBox.Items.Add(account);

        Properties.Settings.Default.Accounts.Add(account);

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        Close();
    }
}
```

[Class "Account"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wD5x.png);

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post all code as text, not an image, Also please read how to create an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.lidorsystems.com/support/articles/winforms/listbox/space-between-items.aspx

This has all 3 things that you asked for.

Spacing:

```
listBox1.ItemSpacing = 10;
```

Indenting each string horizontally:

```
listBox1.ItemFormatStyle.Margin = new Padding(5, 10, 2, 2);

listBox1.ItemFormatStyle.Padding = new Padding(7);
```

Here is how you change the color:

[How to change ListBox selection background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663704/how-to-change-listbox-selection-background-color)

Comment: The fact that you have thrown off, it uses the library, I do not need a library

Comment: Mark Hollis check my screen. Error - ItemFormatStyle

Comment: It is too small, sorry... :( can you post it as text?

Comment: ItemFormatStyle - Missing build reference

Comment: could you describe another way, this way for me does not fit

Comment: I googled your error and nothing came up. Is error longer than that?

Comment: It does not work, because you need a library with dll files