# C# ListBox Item Auto Change Color

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I have a simple question. It took me a long time but I couldn't cope.

I have a ListBox. I get value of 1 from one place. When I get a value I move o a bottom line on ListBox, again and again. But my question is; Can I automatically color each row respectively? I couldn't do it using the draw method.

Comment: Maybe, this post will help you.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663704/how-to-change-listbox-selection-background-color)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change ListBox selection background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663704/how-to-change-listbox-selection-background-color)